# ANSI C - Numerically Stable Back Substitution Algorithm for Upper Right Triangular Matrices

Tags: c, matrix

I'm performing matrix inversion using Householder transformations acting on an augmented matrix. Currently I can only perform accurate inversions for matrix dimensions up to 4x4. After this A*A^-1 != I precisely and I think it's due to back substitution.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: In general, you're always going to be subject to the limitations of floating-point arithmetic.  So in general, that identity will never hold, regardless of the algorithm you use.

Comment: What datatype are your matrices? Can you use [longer floating types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) to maintain accuracy longer?

Comment: If you need highly accurate results, you shouldn't use floating point types at all.

Comment: Why is this better than LU decomposition with pivoting?

Comment: I never said it was better, duffymo. I was asking if there was a better way. I'll take a look at LU decamp with pivoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the 'Householder reflection with back-substitution' method is viable. When verifying that a row has zeros in the proper locations to be part of a matrix in row-echelon form, it is important to compare both the real and imaginary components of a matrix entry to zero, rather than their magnitude.